# How to pass command line args (String array type) to a servlet init method at runtime

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-3.0

I am trying to convert a java desktop application to a web app as the data would be interacting between two different servers.
In desktop app we were getting input in main method using command line args which were set in run configuration.
Now while converting the project in web app, I am not getting how to pass the run time args through servlet.

Desktop app code:

```
public class A extends B {
public static void main(String[] args) {//Get this args value on runtime through arguments set in run configuration
     new A().initialize(args);
    }
    public void initializeProcess(String[] args) {
    ...
     ...
    }
```

Now after converting to servlets:

```
public class A  extends B
 {     
  public void init() throws ServletException
  {
   new A().initializeProcess(args);//How to get this args, as it is throwing errors
}
   public void initializeProcess(String[] args) {
  ....
  ....
 }
```

I tried using init-params in web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>or.com.test</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>args</param-name>
            <param-value>api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Servlet class:

```
public class A  extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException{

                PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
                pw.println(getServletConfig().getInitParameter("args"));

            }

    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
    new A().initializeConsumerProcess(pw);//Not getting how to pass the init param value here
  }
```

How should I pass the program argument value in my servlet class.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an app is started using the command line, you get one running instance of the app in the JVM.  That is why command-line parameters can be used for passing parameters to your app.  This is not the case in webcontainers.  The web container itself may start dozens of applications/servlets.  So which one of that dozen to "pass parameters to" ?  Not doable.  Note that web containers have this feature called "virtual hosts" so it might even be the case that the same application is started more than once, once on each of any number of "virtual hosts".  Configuration for the same app may differ between these "virtual hosts" for any number of good reasons.

A number of alternatives for passing parameters to an application when it is running as a servlet in a web container :

System properties.  They can be defined using -D on the command line used to start the container, or can be defined within the container's settings for a given servlet, if the container has that functionality.

The JNDI system.

Context properties.  Defined within the container for a specific deployment of an application.  Accessing them can be done in your init() method using getContext().getInitParameters() and related methods.

Property files to be deployed with the application (such that the property files appear on the servlet's classpath and are findable using Class.getResource() or some such).  Note that an undeploy will lose the existing configuration info, modulo specific measures to counter this if possible.

Context properties (context init parameters) are probably your best option though it must also be considered who is going to manage these settings and [the ergonomics of] how that is going to be done.

And finally, if the intent of the command-line parameters was specifically and explicitly for the ***end user*** to provide them, then the app will have to be rewritten such that it will present the user with a web page where he can enter the equivalent data.

Comment: Actually In run configurations , program argument I have set one argument which I used to take during desktop application, but now as I have converted it into a web project I am not getting how to take that program argument value now through servlet. How should I set that in web.xml so that I can fetch that value from there or any other way to get program parameter value

Comment: What I tried to explain but apparently failed to do, is that ***there is no such thing*** as "program arguments" (in the sense of stuff that you are given through main(String [] args) ).  In the web.xml, there is the <init-param> tag, which is one possible way for defining context init parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your well explained writeup. I am facing one issue, if you could help me out in this. In (String [] args) we were using array of strings, and what i get from getServletConfig().getInitParameter("args") is a string. This value is then passed in a switch case where conditions are set accordingly. I am not getting how should i get array of string from servlet container. Adding the relevant code too in main question

Comment: Not sure if getServletConfig() is the same thing as getServletContext().  getInitParameter(String) gets you the ***value*** that is configured for the parameter whose name is passed as that String argument.  A method to get all available parameter names is getInitParameterNames().  You can iterate over that.  (PS note that command line arguments may take syntaxes like --setoptionsuchandso but init parameter names are intended to follow the style of name-value pairs, e.g. optionsuchandso:true so following best practices may lead to some rewriting on that level.)